# TAMAÑO LETRA EN ETIQUETAS GRAFICA Highcharts CUANDO SE REFRESCA

Tags: highcharts

Tengo una gráfica donde le defino el tamaño de la letra y en la primera carga sale bien, al momento de refrescar la pantalla la letra cambia de tamaño y se vuelve más pequeña que podrá ser?,
Agradezco en lo que me puedan colaborar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sin ver el codigo que causa esto, va a ser dificil que puedan ayudarte...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.